# In Win UI 3 how can I change the main window page?

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

In Win UI 3 I want to change the content of the MainWindow when the user clicks a button. Right now I have the MainWindow with all its content, then the user clicks a button and a new window opens, let's call it SecondWindow. I do this with:

```
Window secondWindow= new SecondWindow();
secondWindow.Activate();
```

But what I want is for SecondWindow's content to open in the main window, in place of MainWindow's content. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a Frame in MainWindow, and change Frame content instead

Comment: Without knowing WinUI, are you sure you don't want tab controls instead? Or if you are implementing some kind of wizzard, use a control set for that. It's always importnat that the UI is recognizable in some way to the user.

Comment: No, I don't want tab controls, I want it to be slightly more like a phone app, where the view changes and then the user can go back to the main view. @McNets thank you, I was looking into Frames but couldn't figure it out with WinUI 3. I'll try again.

Comment: You can use the latest Template studio for WinUI. It'll help giving you some ideas. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWinUICs

Comment: @McNets Thank you, that was helpful. However, I'm still unsure (I'm pretty new to .NET). I created a template using that template studio with multiple pages, and when I launch the app the Main Window shows, but I can't find the code that is responsible for making it show, so I don't know how to change the view.

Comment: Look at the Helpers folder (Navigation)

Comment: Thanks, I found that. Looking through everything now to try and figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the display the contents of the `secondWindow` inside another window, it should be a `UserControl` instead of a window.

You could then simply add an instance of it as a child of the root panel of the main window:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="root">
...
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
this.grid.Children.Clear();
this.grid.Children.Add(new YourUserControl());
```

If you define the contents directly in a window, you should add its `Content` to the main window like this:

```
Window secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
var root = secondWindow.Content;

this.grid.Children.Clear();
this.grid.Children.Add(root);

secondWindow.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. But when I try it with the UserControl instead of a Window I get the error `cannot convert from MyProject.SecondWindow to Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UIElement`. Any idea why? (This is on the line for `Add(new SecondWindow());`)

Comment: Is `SecondWindow` really a `UserControl`?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the `Window` I had and recreated it as a `UserControl`.

Comment: Well, a `UserControl` is a `UIElement` which means that `SecondWindow` is not really a `UserControl` if you get that error message. Try this: `this.grid.Children.Add(new UserControl() { Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "uc..." } })`.

Comment: I created another UserControl and now have it working, but when I click the button to switch it the program crashes. The same happens with the `Window` code. It works if I put it in `MainWindow()`, but not when it happens on a button click.

Comment: Then you are doing something else as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245851/discussion-between-ricky-kresslein-and-mm8).